# Introspecting _ENV from coroutines

Tags: debugging, reflection, lua, coroutine, introspection

**NB:** I am using Lua version 5.3.

---

This question is motivated by Exercise 25.1 (p. 264) of *Programming in Lua* (4th ed.).  That exercise reads as follows:

> **Exercise 25.1:** Adapt `getvarvalue` (Listing 25.1) to work with different coroutines (like the functions from the `debug` library).

The function `getvarvalue` that the exercise refers to is copied verbatim below.

```
-- Listing 25.1 (p. 256) of *Programming in Lua* (4th ed.)

function getvarvalue (name, level, isenv)
  local value
  local found = false

  level = (level or 1) + 1

  -- try local variables
  for i = 1, math.huge do
    local n, v = debug.getlocal(level, i)
    if not n then break end
    if n == name then
      value = v
      found = true
    end
  end
  if found then return "local", value end

  -- try non-local variables
  local func = debug.getinfo(level, "f").func
  for i = 1, math.huge do
    local n, v = debug.getupvalue(func, i)
    if not n then break end
    if n == name then return "upvalue", v end
  end

  if isenv then return "noenv" end   -- avoid loop

  -- not found; get value from the environment
  local _, env = getvarvalue("_ENV", level, true)
  if env then
    return "global", env[name]
  else        -- no _ENV available
    return "noenv"
  end

end
```

Below is my enhanced version of this function, which implements the additional functionality specified in the exercise.  This version accepts an optional `thread` parameter, expected to be a coroutine.  The only differences between this enhanced version and the original `getvarvalue` are:

1. the handling of the additional optional `thread` parameter;
2. the special setting of the `level` parameter depending on whether the `thread` parameter is the same as the running coroutine or not; and
3. the passing of the `thread` parameter in the calls to `debug.getlocal` and `debug.getinfo`, and in the recursive call.

(I have marked these differences in the source code through numbered comments.)

```
function getvarvalue_enhanced (thread, name, level, isenv)
  -- 1
  if type(thread) ~= "thread" then
    -- (thread, name,  level, isenv)
    -- (name,   level, isenv)
    isenv = level
    level = name
    name = thread
    thread = coroutine.running()
  end

  local value
  local found = false

  -- 2
  level = level or 1
  if thread == coroutine.running() then
    level = level + 1
  end

  -- try local variables
  for i = 1, math.huge do
    local n, v = debug.getlocal(thread, level, i) -- 3
    if not n then break end
    if n == name then
      value = v
      found = true
    end
  end
  if found then return "local", value end

  -- try non-local variables
  local func = debug.getinfo(thread, level, "f").func  -- 3
  for i = 1, math.huge do
    local n, v = debug.getupvalue(func, i)
    if not n then break end
    if n == name then return "upvalue", v end
  end

  if isenv then return "noenv" end   -- avoid loop

  -- not found; get value from the environment
  local _, env = getvarvalue_enhanced(thread, "_ENV", level, true)  -- 3
  if env then
    return "global", env[name]
  else
    return "noenv"
  end

end
```

This function works reasonably well, but I have found one strange situation<sup>1</sup> where it fails.  The function `make_nasty` below generates a coroutine for which `getvarvalue_enhanced` fails to find an `_ENV` variable; i.e. it returns `"noenv"`.  (The function that serves as the basis for `nasty` is the closure `closure_B`, which in turn invokes the closure `closure_A`.  It is `closure_A` that then yields.)

```
function make_nasty ()
  local function closure_A () coroutine.yield() end
  local function closure_B ()
    closure_A()
  end

  local thread = coroutine.create(closure_B)
  coroutine.resume(thread)
  return thread
end

nasty = make_nasty()
print(getvarvalue_enhanced(nasty, "_ENV", 2))
-- noenv
```

In contrast, the almost identical function `make_nice` produces a coroutine for which `getvarvalue_enhanced` succeeds in finding an `_ENV` variable.

```
function make_nice ()
  local function closure_A () coroutine.yield() end
  local function closure_B ()
    local _ = one_very_much_non_existent_global_variable  -- only difference!
    closure_A()
  end

  local thread = coroutine.create(closure_B)
  coroutine.resume(thread)
  return thread
end

nice = make_nice()
print(getvarvalue_enhanced(nice, "_ENV", 2))
-- upvalue  table: 0x558a2633c930
```

The only difference between `make_nasty` and `make_nice` is that, in the latter, the closure `closure_B` references a non-existent global variable (and does nothing with it).

**Q:** How can I modify `getvarvalue_enhanced` so that it is able to locate `_ENV` for `nasty`, the way it does for `nice`?

---

EDIT: changed the names of the closures within `make_nasty` and `make_nice`.

---

EDIT2: the wording of Exercise 25.3 (same page) may be relevant here (my emphasis):

> **Exercise 25.3:** Write a version of `getvarvalue` (Listing 25.1) that returns a table with all variables *that are visible* at the calling function.  (The returned table should not include environmental variables; instead it should inherit them from the original environment.)

This question implies that there should be a way to get at the variables that are *merely visible* from a function, *whether the function uses them or not*.  Such variables would certainly include `_ENV`.  (The author is one of Lua's creators, so he knows what he's talking about.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I am sure that someone with a better understanding of what is going on in this example will be able to come up with a less convoluted way to elicit the same behavior.  The example I present here is the most minimal form I can come up with of the situation I found by accident.</sup>

Comment: I'll say this to be safe: don't use code like that in production. It breaks as soon as you precompile code without debug symbols. it should only ever be used for ad-hoc debugging or optional debugging components.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer: thank you for the advice.  To be clear, which code are you referring to?  All the code in the post?

Comment: In general, don't rely on `debug`, but more precisely, everything that relies on variable names completely breaks if you strip debug symbols when compiling with `luac`. It's only really viable when you're in control of what code you work with, so not at all when writing a library to publish.

Answer (score 1):

```
  local function inner_closure () coroutine.yield() end
  local function outer_closure ()
    inner_closure()
  end
```

> The function make_nasty below generates a coroutine for which getvarvalue_enhanced fails to find an _ENV variable; i.e. it returns "noenv"

That's a correct behavior.
The closure `outer_closure` has upvalue `inner_closure` but doesn't have upvalue `_ENV`.
This is how lexical scope works.
It's OK that some closures don't have `_ENV` upvalue.

In your example the closure `inner_closure` isn't defined inside the body of `outer_closure`.
`inner_closure` is not nested in `outer_closure`.

Comment: Thank you, but your answer does not address at all the question that I actually asked at the end of my post.

Comment: @kjo - You can explicitly insert the line `_ENV=_ENV` into `outer_closure` so that it surely has `_ENV` upvalue.  If you're not able to modify `outer_closure` then you're unable to get its `_ENV` because it doesn't have it.  But it has an upvalue that does have the upvalue `_ENV`, so you might try to search the whole tree of dependencies :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible.

If a closure doesn't make any use of the global environment `_ENV`, then it doesn't have that upvalue whatsoever.

A function like

```lua
local something = 20

local function noupval(x, y)
   return x * y
end
```

Doesn't need or have any upvalues, not even to the global environment.

---

> This question implies that there should be a way to get at the variables that are merely visible from a function, whether the function uses them or not.

There really isn't though. You can easily confirm this by looking at the output of `luac -p -l <your_code.lua>`, more precisely at the upvalues of each function.

If anything, I think using the word *visible* is somewhat misleading there. Visibility really only matters when **creating** a closure, but once it has been closed, that closure only  has a set of upvalues which it can access.

---

> Exercise 25.3: Write a version of getvarvalue (Listing 25.1) that returns a table with all variables that are visible at the calling function. (The returned table should not include environmental variables; instead it should inherit them from the original environment.)

You may have misunderstood that exercise; the way I understand it is something like this:

```lua
local upvalue = 20
local function foo()
  local var = upvalue -- Create 1 local and access 1 upvalue
  type(print) == "function" -- Access _ENV so it becomes an upvalue
  return getvarvalue_enhanced()
end
```

and the above would return `{var = 20, upvalue = 20, _ENV = <Proxy table to _ENV>}`

After all, it asks specifically about the *calling* function, not one you pass as a parameter.

This doesn't change the fact that you still only get `_ENV` if you access it though. If you don't use any globals, the function won't have any reference to `_ENV` whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you for these observations.  Your `noupval` example is a bit misleading/confusing, though, because, after all, no upvalues are even defined outside of it, whether it uses it or not.  Your point would be clearer (to me at least) if you added a `local something = ...`  before the definition of `noupval`.

Comment: Please see my EDIT2; it may be relevant to your answer.

Comment: @kjo I expanded my answer a bit ;)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - `{var = 20, upvalue = 20, _ENV = <Global Environment>}` Probably this is not what was asked for.  It's not enough to put `_ENV` in the table.  "Inherit env variables" means create a metatable for such inheritance.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That's true, I seem to have misunderstood that the first time. Either way, implementing that is a completely different proble than what OP asked for, so I'm not going to expand my answer with an explanationof how to do this.